# How to fix issue when loading CR only delimited File text in Delphi 7 ?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, text-files

I have a big text file (about 100MB) and each lines are separated by CR character, and not CRLF.

I tried to read this text file, line by line using TStringList.LoadFromFile() or ReadLn(F,..), but both methods require the lines are separated by CRLF.

Do you have any efficient and fast method to read this kind of text file?

Thanks.

PS: I am using Delphi 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it.
Read the text file into a memory stream.
Then fill the string list with the contents.
`textList.Text` accepts any combination of `CR`,`LF` and `CRLF` to form a line.

```
function MemoryStreamToString( M : TMemoryStream) : string;
begin
  SetString( Result,PChar(M.Memory),M.Size div SizeOf(Char)); // Works in all Delphi versions
end;

var
  memStream : TMemoryStream;
  textList  : TStringList;
begin
  textList := TStringList.Create; 
  try
    memStream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      memStream.LoadFromFile('mytextfile.txt');
      textList.Text := MemoryStreamToString( memStream);  // any combination of CR,LF,CRLF interprets as a line
    finally
      memStream.Free;
    end;
    // do something with textList

  finally
    textList.Free;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: I got compile error "Incompatible types" on SetString( Result,M.Memory,M.Size);

Comment: I changed to SetString(Result, PChar(M.Memory), Integer(M.Size)); and it got compiled. But, if I checked the textList.count, result is 1. So, the conversion is not correct. The text files contains multiple lines, each ended with CR. Your function convert the whole lines into one string, which is wrong.

Comment: Strange, this is from the help file : `When setting Text, the value will be parsed by separating into substrings whenever a carriage return or linefeed is encountered. (The two do not need to form pairs).` This is the same since at least Delphi5.

Comment: I made a test in Delphi5, inserting #13 randomly in a text file. For sure, the documentation is correct and the above presented code works. (Added PChar around M.Memory).

Comment: You right, it is working as I tested with other small file. I think, there is other problem with my test file. It consist a lot of #0 chars in between.

Comment: Since you might some day need to read a file line by line that is too big to fit in memory, I have submitted an alternative answer that is as memory-efficient as the `ReadLn` appoach, but which tolerates any sort of line-ending you could reasonably imagine encountering.

Comment: I could not get this to work in XE2, the text list is filled with Chinese characters, so there's some memory mapping issue. @WarrenP's solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

I have always wanted a solution for this problem, and so I wrote one, which is part of JvCsvDataSet.  My problems were:

1. I want to read a file that might have CR, CR+LF, or just LF endings.
2. I want something like ReadLn, but which is really flexible about point #1, and which does not have ReadLn's well-known problems. So Ancient Pascal had the Textfile type, and the ReadLn procedure.  A modern Class equivalent is needed.
3. I would like it to be a stream-like object so I can read line by line, and not load my entire 3.7 gigabyte megabyte file into memory. Also, I want the Position to be Int64 type, and I want to be able to handle very large files (>2 gb).
4. I want this to work in Delphi 7, and also in Delphi XE2, and everything in between.
5. I wanted it to be very very very fast.  So I spent some time optimizing block read performance, and parsing.

So here is what you would write if you want to do this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
ts:TTextStream;
s:String;
begin
 ts := TTextStream.Create('c:\temp\test.txt', fm_OpenReadShared);
 try
 while not ts.Eof do begin
   s := ts.ReadLine;
   doSomethingWith(s);
 end;
 finally
    ts.Free;
 end;
end;
```

Okay. That looks easy right? It is. And it's even got a file mode flag (notice the read-shared option there?). Now all you need is Teh Codez For TTextStream, which are here:

```
unit textStreamUnit;
{$M+}


{$R-}

{
  textStreamUnit

  This code is based on some of the content of the JvCsvDataSet written by Warren Postma, and others,
  licensed under MOZILLA Public License.
 }

interface

uses
  Windows,
  Classes,
  SysUtils;


const
  cQuote = #34;
  cLf    = #10;
  cCR    = #13;

 { File stream mode flags used in TTextStream }

  { Significant 16 bits are reserved for standard file stream mode bits. }
  { Standard system values like fmOpenReadWrite are in SysUtils. }
  fm_APPEND_FLAG  = $20000;
  fm_REWRITE_FLAG = $10000;

  { combined Friendly mode flag values }
  fm_Append          = fmOpenReadWrite or fm_APPEND_FLAG;
  fm_OpenReadShared  = fmOpenRead      or fmShareDenyWrite;
  fm_OpenRewrite     = fmOpenReadWrite or fm_REWRITE_FLAG;
  fm_Truncate        = fmCreate        or fm_REWRITE_FLAG;
  fm_Rewrite         = fmCreate        or fm_REWRITE_FLAG;

  TextStreamReadChunkSize = 8192; // 8k chunk reads.

resourcestring
    RsECannotReadFile = 'Cannot read file %';


type
  ETextStreamException = class(Exception);

{$ifndef UNICODE}
  RawByteString=AnsiString;
{$endif}

  TTextStream = class(TObject)
  private
    FStream: TFileStream; // Tried TJclFileStream also but it was too slow! Do NOT use JCL streams here. -wpostma.
    FFilename: string;
    FStreamBuffer: PAnsiChar;
    FStreamIndex: Integer;
    FStreamSize: Integer;
    FLastReadFlag: Boolean;

    procedure _StreamReadBufInit;
  public
    function ReadLine: RawByteString;   { read a string, one per line, wow. Text files. Cool eh?}

    procedure Append;
    procedure Rewrite;

    procedure Write(const s: RawByteString);        {write a string. wow, eh? }
    procedure WriteLine(const s: RawByteString);    {write string followed by Cr+Lf }

    procedure WriteChar(c: AnsiChar);

    procedure WriteCrLf;
    //procedure Write(const s: string);

    function Eof: Boolean; {is at end of file? }

    { MODE is typically a fm_xxx constant thatimplies a default set of stream mode bits plus some extended bit flags that are specific to this stream type.}
    constructor Create(const FileName: string; Mode: DWORD = fm_OpenReadShared; Rights: Cardinal = 0); reintroduce; virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    function Size: Int64; //override;   // sanity

    { read-only properties at runtime}
    property Filename: string read FFilename;
    property Stream: TFileStream read FStream; { Get at the underlying stream object}
  end;

implementation





// 2 gigabyte file limit workaround:
function GetFileSizeEx(h: HFILE; FileSize: PULargeInteger): BOOL; stdcall;  external Kernel32;

procedure TTextStream.Append; 
begin
  Stream.Seek(0, soFromEnd);
end;

constructor TTextStream.Create(const FileName: string; Mode: DWORD; Rights: Cardinal);
var
  IsAppend: Boolean;
  IsRewrite: Boolean;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FFilename := FileName;

  FLastReadFlag := False;
  IsAppend := (Mode and fm_APPEND_FLAG) <> 0;
  IsRewrite := (Mode and fm_REWRITE_FLAG) <> 0;

  FStream := TFileStream.Create(Filename, {16 lower bits only}Word(Mode), Rights);

  //Stream := FStream; { this makes everything in the base class actually work if we inherited from Easy Stream}

  if IsAppend then
    Self.Append  // seek to the end.
  else
    Stream.Position := 0;

  if IsRewrite then
    Rewrite;

  _StreamReadBufInit;
end;

destructor TTextStream.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FStream) then
    FStream.Position := 0; // avoid nukage
  FreeAndNil(FStream);
  FreeMem(FStreamBuffer); // Buffered reads for speed.
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TTextStream.Eof: Boolean;
begin
  if not Assigned(FStream) then
    Result := False
    //Result := True
  else
    Result := FLastReadFlag and (FStreamIndex >= FStreamSize);
    //Result := FStream.Position >= FStream.Size;
end;

{ TTextStream.ReadLine:
  This reads a line of text, normally terminated by carriage return and/or linefeed
  but it is a bit special, and adapted for CSV usage because CR/LF characters
  inside quotes are read as a single line.

  This is a VERY PERFORMANCE CRITICAL function. We loop tightly inside here.
  So there should be as few procedure-calls inside the repeat loop as possible.


}
function TTextStream.ReadLine: RawByteString;
var
  Buf: array of AnsiChar;
  n: Integer;
  QuoteFlag: Boolean;
  LStreamBuffer: PAnsiChar;
  LStreamSize: Integer;
  LStreamIndex: Integer;

  procedure FillStreamBuffer;
  begin
    FStreamSize := Stream.Read(LStreamBuffer[0], TextStreamReadChunkSize);
    LStreamSize := FStreamSize;
    if LStreamSize = 0 then
    begin
      if FStream.Position >= FStream.Size then
        FLastReadFlag := True
      else
        raise ETextStreamException.CreateResFmt(@RsECannotReadFile, [FFilename]);
    end
    else
    if LStreamSize < TextStreamReadChunkSize then
      FLastReadFlag := True;
    FStreamIndex := 0;
    LStreamIndex := 0;
  end;

begin
  { Ignore linefeeds, read until carriage return, strip carriage return, and return it }
  SetLength(Buf, 150);

  n := 0;
  QuoteFlag := False;

  LStreamBuffer := FStreamBuffer;
  LStreamSize := FStreamSize;
  LStreamIndex := FStreamIndex;
  while True do
  begin
    if n >= Length(Buf) then
      SetLength(Buf, n + 100);

    if LStreamIndex >= LStreamSize then
      FillStreamBuffer;

    if LStreamIndex >= LStreamSize then
      Break;

    Buf[n] := LStreamBuffer[LStreamIndex];
    Inc(LStreamIndex);

    case Buf[n] of
      cQuote: {34} // quote
        QuoteFlag := not QuoteFlag;
      cLf: {10} // linefeed
        if not QuoteFlag then
          Break;
      cCR: {13} // carriage return
        begin
          if not QuoteFlag then
          begin
            { If it is a CRLF we must skip the LF. Otherwise the next call to ReadLine
              would return an empty line. }
            if LStreamIndex >= LStreamSize then
              FillStreamBuffer;
            if LStreamBuffer[LStreamIndex] = cLf then
              Inc(LStreamIndex);

            Break;
          end;
        end
    end;
    Inc(n);
  end;
  FStreamIndex := LStreamIndex;

  SetString(Result, PAnsiChar(@Buf[0]), n);
end;

procedure TTextStream.Rewrite;
begin
  if Assigned(FStream) then
    FStream.Size := 0;// truncate!
end;

function TTextStream.Size: Int64; { Get file size }
begin
  if Assigned(FStream) then
    GetFileSizeEx(FStream.Handle, PULargeInteger(@Result)) {int64 Result}
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

{ Look at this. A stream that can handle a string parameter. What will they think of next? }
procedure TTextStream.Write(const s: RawByteString);
begin
  Stream.Write(s[1], Length(s)); {The author of TStreams would like you not to be able to just write Stream.Write(s).  Weird. }
end;

procedure TTextStream.WriteChar(c: AnsiChar);
begin
  Stream.Write(c, SizeOf(AnsiChar));
end;

procedure TTextStream.WriteCrLf;
begin
  WriteChar(#13);
  WriteChar(#10);
end;

procedure TTextStream.WriteLine(const s: RawByteString);
begin
  Write(s);
  WriteCrLf;
end;

procedure TTextStream._StreamReadBufInit;
begin
  if not Assigned(FStreamBuffer) then
  begin
    //FStreamBuffer := AllocMem(TextStreamReadChunkSize);
    GetMem(FStreamBuffer, TextStreamReadChunkSize);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: This worked perfectly in Delphi XE2 where the other answers failed. Thanks for Warren. Blast from the past :)

Comment: Awesome. I love this little utility class.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you need to set the LineBreak property of the stringlist before reading the text from file.

```
....
const 
  CR = #13;
  LF = #10;
  LFCR = #10#13;
begin
  MyStringList.LineBreak:= CR;
  MyStringList.LoadFromFile(.....
```

See: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Classes.TStrings.LineBreak

Not 100% sure Delphi 7 supports this (just checked, D2007 does so I suspect D7 will too).

Comment: No, Delphi 7 does not have this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2957614/1046041

At first look, it seems that you could change in the code the EOL character to something else then #13#10.

It also parses line by line (you could use this as a buffer) instead of loading the whole file into memory (that might be a problem for a 100MB+ file).

Comment: Loading TStrings content from file is the same memory-greedy as loading its Text property.