# Why does ReadLn mis-interpret UTF8 text when non-unicode page is Korean (949)?

Tags: delphi, unicode, utf-8, codepages

In Delphi XE2 I can only read and display unicode characters (from a UTF8 encoded file) when the system locale is English using the `AssignFile` and `ReadLn()` routines.

**Where it fails**
If I set the system locale for non-unicode applications to Korean (codepage 949, I think) and repeat the same read, some of my UTF8 multi-byte pairs get replaced with `$3F`.  This only applies to using `ReadLn` and not when using `TFile.ReadAllText(aFilename, TEncoding.UTF8)` or `TFileStream.Read()`.

**The test**
1. I create a text file, UTF8 w/o BOM (Notepad++) with following characters (hex equivalent shown on second line):

```
테스트
ed 85 8c ec 8a a4 ed 8a b8
```

2. Write a Delphi XE 2 Windows form application with TMemo control:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.ReadFile(aFilename:string);
   var
     gFile     : TextFile;
     gLine     : RawByteString;
     gWideLine : string;
   begin
     AssignFile(gFile, aFilename);
     try
       Reset(gFile);
       Memo1.Clear;
       while not EOF(gFile) do
       begin
         ReadLn(gFile, gLine);
         gWideLine := UTF8ToWideString(gLine);
         Memo1.Lines.Add(gWideLine);
       end;
     finally
       CloseFile(gFile);
     end;
   end;
   ```
3. I inspect the contents of `gLine` before performing a `UTF8ToWideString` conversation and under English / US locale Windows it is:

   `$ED $85 $8C $EC $8A $A4 $ED $8A $B8`

As an aside, if I read the same file with a BOM I get the correct 3 byte preamble and the output when the UTF8 decode is performed is the same.  All OK so far!

4. Switch Windows 7 (x64) to use Korean as the codepage for applications without Unicode support (Region and Language --> Administrative tab --> Change system locale --> Korean (Korea).  Restart computer.
5. Read same file (UTF8 w/o BOM) with above application and `gLine` now has hex value:

   `$3F $8C $EC $8A $A4 $3F $3F`

   Output in TMemo: ?�스??
6. Hypothesis that `ReadLn()` (and `Read()` for that matter) are attempting to map UTF8 sequences as Korean multibyte sequences (i.e. Tries to interpret $ED $85, can't and so subs in question mark $3F).
7. Use `TFileStream` to read in exactly the expected number of bytes (9 w/o BOM) and the hex in memory is now exactly:

   `$ED $85 $8C $EC $8A $A4 $ED $8A $B8`

   Output in TMemo: 테스트 (perfect!)

**Problem:** Laziness - I've a lot of legacy routines that parse potentially large files line by line and I wanted to be sure I didn't need to write a routine to manually read until new lines for each of these files.

**Question(s):**

1. Why is `Read()` not returning me the exact byte string as found in the file?  Is it because I'm using a `TextFile` type and so Delphi is doing a degree of interpretation using the non-unicode codepage?
2. Is there a built in way to read a UTF8 encoded file line by line?

**Update:**

Just came across Rob Kennedy's solution to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815839/delphi-alternative-to-using-reset-readln-for-text-file-reading) which reintroduces me to TStreamReader, which answers the question about graceful reading of UTF8 files line by line.

Comment: `Readln`, and indeed `Writeln` don't properly support Unicode encodings. This question is related

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255148/is-writeln-capable-of-supporting-unicode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a built in way to read a UTF8 encoded file line by line?

Use [`TStreamReader`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TStreamReader).  It has a [`ReadLine()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TStreamReader.ReadLine) method.

```
    procedure TForm1.ReadFile(aFilename:string);
    var
      gFile     : TStreamReader;
      gLine     : string;
    begin
      Memo1.Clear;
      gFile := TStreamReader.Create(aFilename, TEncoding.UTF8, True);
      try
        while not gFile.EndOfStream do
        begin
          gLine := gFile.ReadLine;
          Memo1.Lines.Add(gLine);
        end;
      finally
        gFile.Free;
      end;
    end;
```

With that said, this particular example can be greatly simplified:

```
    procedure TForm1.ReadFile(aFilename:string);
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(aFilename, TEncoding.UTF8);
    end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy for going the distance and creating a nice example of the TStreamReader solution.